# Getting an error while making the below staticInitialisation advice generic

Tags: aop, aspectj, aspect

Since the below given advice works only for a specific class

```java
@Before("staticinitialization(org.mazouz.aop.Main1)")
```

I tried to make the advice generic such that it can work for any package

```java
@Before("staticinitialization(*.*.*(..))")
```

Im getting the below error

```
Syntax error on token "staticinitialization(*.*.*(..))", ")" expected
```